# Same CommandArgument for two different linkbutton

Tags: c#, linkbutton, commandargument

First I gave to my first button the CommandArguments

```
btnDateModif.CommandArgument = hebergement.Attributes["IdInterne"].Value;
```

Then I'm using the button like this

```
 protected void BtnModifDate_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            PanelModifDate.Visible = true;
            PanelHebergement.Visible = false;
        }

        protected void BtnEnregistreDate_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckValidDate();
            PanelModifDate.Visible = false;
            PanelHebergement.Visible = true;
        }
```

My question is how I can give the CommandArgument of the first button to the other one ?

Comment: Have you tried get btnEnregistreDate.CommandArgument = btnDateModif.CommandArgument ? also can you give some more information what you ve tried and couldn't succeed

Comment: The first button is in a Reapeter ans the second is in a Panel so I don't think I can do it like that.